# Azure Devops - Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Service Connection

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a PowerShell script which I would like to move into an Azure DevOps pipeline.

The PowerShell script does a `Connect-AzAccount` and then iterates over all ~300 subscriptions which my account can see:

```
foreach ( $Subscription in $(Get-AzSubscription | Where-Object { $_.State -ne "Disabled" }) ) {...}
```

The DevOps pipeline uses a service connection within the `AzurePowerShell@5` task:

```
- task:  AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
    ConnectedServiceNameARM: test-infosec-connection
    scriptPath: './_AzureWafCompliance.ps1'
    pwsh: true
```

The job runs and finishes successfully but the issue is that it only iterates over one subscription i.e. the ARM service connection subscription.

Within the debug can be seen that the AzurePowerShell task runs the following commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope

 Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx -TenantId xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
```

I suspect it's the second command which locks me into the subscription. Is there another/better approach to this, or any way to change the default behaviour of the AzurePowershell task?

Answer (score 1):

Azure PowerShell task is used to run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment. The Azure context is authenticated with the provided Azure Resource Manager service connection.

Locally, the script runs with your credentials and would succeed as you may have the required access.

When creating ARM service connection Subscription, the Azure Subscription must be chosen.

[image]

So your Azure PowerShell task only iterates over this chosen Azure Subscription.

Using the ARM service connection Management Group instead of ARM service connection Subscription: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview

[image]